# C++ - Automatic Class Loading from DLL (Windows, Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, dll

I have a base class CDemonstration and multiple subclasses (each implementation runs a different coding Demonstration) and need to build a Main Menu (vector) containing one instance of each subclass. The goal is to maintain a Menu which lists each Demonstration with the least amount of effort.

Originally in the core application, I made a function which returns a vector containing one instance of each Demonstration, where each Demonstration required a push_back, and each new Demonstration required modification to the application by adding another push_back. To avoid altering the application's source code each time I need to add a new Demonstration to add to the list, I placed all of the Demonstrations into a separate DLL, and I created the same vector-returning function in the DLL so that it can be called from the core application. However, the work related to building/maintaining that list of Demonstrations has simply been pushed somewhere else.

I'd like to do one of the following:

- Loop through each class in the DLL of type CDemonstration, use its default constructor to initialize it, and add it to the vector.
- Add a static virtual const Factory function to the base class, implement it in each subclass, and then loop through each of these Factory functions to get the instances to add to the vector.

This sounds a lot like Reflection and may not even be appropriate in general C++, but it would be really nice to somehow add new Demonstrations to the list simply by virtue of them having implemented CDemonstration, vs. building an explicit list of each Demonstration.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have each derived class in a separate DLL you could:

1. Use filesystem APIs to create a list of DLLs in a specific folder
2. Load each of them and call an API that returns a handle to the specific menu objects.
3. Add the objects by using the base class pointer type (just ensure any specific behavior is implemented as a virtual method)

Comment: Good idea! If each DLL contains a factory function with the same name and signature, then I can load a folder of DLLs to get a set of menu options.

One issue I see is that I could potentially have hundreds of demonstrations and creating a new project per demonstration is a lot of overhead

Comment: (Sorry, edited.)

Good idea! If each DLL contains a factory function, and each DLL's factory function shares the same name and signature as the others, then I can load a folder of DLLs to get a set of menu options.

One issue I have is that I'm left with multiple factory functions initializing one class each instead of one factory function initializing all classes, plus the overhead of each project.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. As you said, whether I put them all in the same DLL or split them across multiple DLLs, each DLL needs an API function with which each concrete implementation contained within that DLL is registered. Without Reflection or a lot of raw DLL digging, I don't believe there's a way to just "call the static Factory method of all classes derived from base class X".